# Error in code as3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have a folder contains swf and xml files.

This is my AS3 code :

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

function loadMyswf(url:String):void {
    var myswf:Loader = new Loader();
    var url2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("");
    myswf.load(url2);
    addChild(myswf);  
}
```

I try to load an swf file using a `Loader` ( `myswf` ) when the user click on the [AccordionTreeMenu V3](http://www.jumpeyecomponents.com/Flash-Components/Flash-Menus/Accordion-Tree-Menu-V3-36/) component, but that is not working.

So, what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: none of what you say makes any sense.

Comment: Why???
I have a list in FLA ..I want to open swf file in myMovieclip

Comment: you talk about an error that we never see anywhere, you try to load ... nothing? : new URLRequest(""); <- that is nothing. That code obviously does nothing at all and there's nowhere to be found error or Flex.

Comment: I load Example [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BcYjTM8tPoNllEWHhQdzFYWk0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @akmozo can you help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your `loadMySwf` function where you forgot to pass the path of the loaded file to the `URLRequest` object, so it should be like this :

```
function loadMyswf(url:String):void {
    var myswf:Loader = new Loader();
    var url2:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);  // here you should pass the url/path of the file
    myswf.load(url2);
    addChild(myswf);  
}
```

**Edit :**

To resize your loaded content you can do like this :

```
var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('01.swf');
var swf_loader:Loader = new Loader();
    swf_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_Loaded);    
    swf_loader.load(url_request);
function on_Loaded(e:Event): void {
    swf_loader.width = 50;
    swf_loader.height = 50;
    addChild(swf_loader);
}
```

---

Don't forget to put all the details that can help others to understand your problem and to help you to resolve it.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks very much akmozo
but How to do open swf file in movie clip myswf

Comment: Because  swf file opens in full stage

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help

Comment: @FlashGirl You can resize the loaded content if you want, but I think it's better to adapt your loaded contents to your Stage.

Comment: The problem how to Return To list??

Comment: @FlashGirl As I told you, you have to adapt your loaded content to your Stage so you can use the back button at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: addChild(myswf).width = swf.width;
 addChild(myswf).height = swf.height;
 addChild(myswf).x = swf.x;
 addChild(myswf).y = swf.y;
 setChildIndex(myswf,swf+1);

Comment: >> hi  akmozo ,i have a problem in swf_loader ?

Comment: swf_loader File does not work will correct  at loaded in stage > When  i select X, y >>swf_loader.x= 50;
    swf_loader.y= 50;

Comment: @FlashGirl What's the problem with swf_loader ?

Comment: Buttons do not work, or when clicking on it or select an item in which

Comment: @FlashGirl I can't understand the problem, try to explain please.

Comment: May be because
I changed X and Y

Comment: How I do,, download swf file in the center in stage without change x and y ?

Comment: swf_loader.align = Stage.align.CENTER; ...>>>does not work